# USB flash drive for long term usage (1 year)

Tags: windows-7, usb

I would like to store data output from my application. I would like to store the data into USB  flash drive.

My application will generate about 100 bytes sized data every 10 seconds. These data will be stored into files. The files will be separated on daily basis.

My question is what I should care to use USB flash drive as a data storage. I will plan to use the storage for about a year.

I am concerned about unmount of the USB flash drive on some occasion by Window7 OS. What should I take measure to prevent unmount and other related problem for long term use?

Comment: If Windows 7 is running and your program is keeping a file on the flash drive open, then Windows will not unmount the flash drive (never seen the message "Can't unmount the drive, it's busy" when trying to unmount a drive manually?).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, it seems dangerous to keep the file open for a longer period. My original plan was to open/write/close file every 10 seconds. However, according to reply by Rob, I had better rethink the frequency of file writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen Windows 7 unmount a flash drive unless I shut down Windows or unplugged the flash drive.  You may be thinking of the power-saving feature that's built into spindle-based hard drives which spins down those drives and puts them to sleep after a period of inactivity.

The longevity of your media (in read/write cycles) won't be an issue if you're only writing 100B every 10s for one year, but you may want to rethink your storage scheme for several performance reasons that I'll discuss in more detail below.

The block size of the filesystem will dictate the smallest allocated file size and will almost certainly be larger than 100B.  For example, if the block size is 4KB, then space will be allocated in 4KB chunks.  A 100B file will consume 4KB space, and a 4097KB file (4KB+1B) will be allocated 8KB (2 blocks).  That said, most flash drives should still have plenty of capacity for 1 year of data at the rate you expect.

If you're generating dozens or hundreds (or, in your case, 8640) of files per day with similar names in a single directory, you'll want to make sure 8.3 filename support is disabled in the registry (or make sure your filenames are no longer than 8 characters and the extensions are no longer than 3 characters).  If you have a bunch of files that start with the word *filename* and end with *.txt*, for example, you'll end up with the following 8.3 filenames:

```
FILENA~1.TXT
FILENA~2.TXT
FILENA~3.TXT
...
FILEN~10.TXT
FILEN~11.TXT
...
FILE~100.TXT
```

...and so on.

The cost of computing these filenames increases exponentially with the number of files, and even getting a directory listing is slowed down dramatically.

One last factor is the cost of a random read/write operation on your flash storage.  If you've ever copied lots of small files to or from a flash drive, you know that many USB flash drives have horrible random read/write performance.  It may take many orders of magnitude longer to copy thousands of small files off the flash drive after 1 year than it would to copy just dozens or hundreds of files, even if the total file size is the same.  It could mean the difference between hours vs. seconds to copy all your data.

For these reasons, consider creating a new file about every hour or every day instead, create additional levels in your directory structure (like per hour), or store the data in a database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. It helps a lot. So rather than unmount thing, I have to take care for 8.3 file name, number of files and frequency of file save operations. I will take these in consideration. Best regards.